# bcrypt is not returning anything NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, es6-promise

THIS ALWAYS USED TO WORK, somehow this is not working for me :

The thing that I am using to compare the password:

```
router.post("/login", [
    check('email', 'Email is required').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Password is required').not().isEmpty()
    ], async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if ( !errors.isEmpty() || !email || !password ) {
        return res.status(401).json({err: "Authentication failure"});
    };
    try {
        const user = User.findOne({ email: email });
        if(!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({err: "Invalid username or password"});
        }
        const isValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);  //// <-------HERE!!!!!
        console.log("Not reaching here")
        if (!isValidPassword) {
            return res.status(401).json({err: "Invalid username or password"});
        }
        //if valid password 
        res.status(200).send("SUCCESS");
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({err: "Internal server error"});
    }
})
```

Can someone help me out? This is the first time I'm stuck here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it send the internal server error response? Have you tried `console.log(error)` in the catch block?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using "await" while making a DB query!
correction:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
```